# get the coordinate place on the table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i have problem with thinking to solve this logarithm and it will be soo soo good if the answer wana be with angularjs javascript.

My question is i have this table: http://jsfiddle.net/zdtvy1h1/2/

How can i get the current coordinate place after any clicked.

To explain my question more than: http://jsfiddle.net/zdtvy1h1/2/

This is a photo about my Table and what i want : if i clicked on 14 to get the coordinate for it and the value wana be for number 14 is `ENG209` and `12:00-13:00` also if i clicked on number 23 to get `ENG214 14:00-15:00`.

I hope i sent good question for you to understand it.

**notice** 1 : the number which in the photo it's just an example i need to put some thing else

**notice 2 :** I'm using database to get this value from it

[image: example]

```
<div class="panel panel-Technical text-center">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            <i class="fa  fa-institution"> </i>
            Monday
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive text-center">
    <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr class="text-center">
                <th>#</th>
                <th>ENG201</th>
                <th>ENG209</th>
                <th>ENG214</th>
                <th>EBN204</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">9:00-10:00</th>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">10:00-11:00</th>
                  <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
            </tr>                  
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">11:00-12:00 </th>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>12</td>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">12:00-13:00</th>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>16</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">13:00-14:00</th>
                <td>17</td>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">14:00-15:00</th>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>24</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="aaa" scope="row" >15:00-16:00</th>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>26</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>28</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">16:00-17:00</th>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>31</td>
                <td>32</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the table please? EDIT: thanks :)

Comment: Do you care using jquery?

Comment: yes no problem if i will take the value i can pass it to my angular after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this! Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zdtvy1h1/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td').click(function() {
        var subject = $("tr.text-center th").get($(this).index());
        alert($(this).parent().find('th[scope="row"]').text()+" "+$(subject).text());
    });
});
```

It first searches the subject by indexing the child number `$(this).index()` and than looking what child in the header belongs to the clicked tr `var subject = ...`. Next it finds `th` with `scope=row` that is in the same `tr` with `.find('th[scope="row"]')`.

But it's all very compact :)

Enjoy!

**EDIT:**

This is essentially the same script but now you have the variables `subject` and `time` that you can pass on to your AngularJS

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('td').click(function() {
        var subject = $("tr.text-center th").get($(this).index());
        subject = $(subject).text();
        var time = $(this).parent().find('th[scope="row"]').text();

        alert(time+" "+subject);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you soo soo soo much :) that so good and it's worked with me

Answer (score 2):

If you layout your table using an ng-repeat with a collection of objects (each representing a row of data) you can use ng-click to fire off a function, passing in the object representing that row.

Something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in vm.tableData" ng-click=vm.selectRow(row);>
    <td ....>
    <td ....>
    <td ....>
</tr>
```

In your controller define vm.tableData as an array of objects containing your data. vm.selectRow is a function that takes in a data object and does whatever you need done.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are including jQuery use `index()`

```
$('tbody td').click(function(){
   var rowIndex = $(this).parent().index();
   var colIndex = $(this).index();    
});
```

WHen used with no arguments it returns index of the element within it's siblings